# Convert a single string formatted as a csv file into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have an extremely long single python string which is formatted as a csv file. A shortened version looks like this.

```
"1,1,6;3,6,2;3,3,1;"
```

How could I turn this into a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: what kind of dataframe do you expect? what is the separator - coma or semicolon?

Comment: The separator for each row is ; and the separator for each item in the row is ,

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_records(csv.reader("1,1,6;3,6,2;3,3,1;".split(";")))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** - using `lineterminator` parameter makes it very simple:

```
In [77]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('1,1,6;3,6,2;3,3,1;'), lineterminator=';', header=None)
Out[77]:
   0  1  2
0  1  1  6
1  3  6  2
2  3  3  1
```

**OLD answer:**

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join("1,1,6;3,6,2;3,3,1;".split(';'))), header=None)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  1  6
1  3  6  2
2  3  3  1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works a charm!